# How to use spring annotations like @Autowired in kotlin?

Tags: spring, kotlin

Is it possible to do something like following in Kotlin?

```
@Autowired
internal var mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate

@Autowired
internal var solrClient: SolrClient
```

Comment: Have you tried? And to be a bit more constructive.. there's an entire [Spring Boot template](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/spring-boot-restful.html), the answer is most certainly "yes".

Comment: @mabi thank you for the tutorial link :)

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Recommended approach to do Dependency Injection in Spring is constructor injection:

```
@Component
class YourBean(
    private val mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate, 
    private val solrClient: SolrClient
) {
  // code
}
```

Prior to Spring 4.3 constructor should be explicitly annotated with `Autowired`:

```
@Component
class YourBean @Autowired constructor(
    private val mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate, 
    private val solrClient: SolrClient
) {
  // code
}
```

In rare cases, you might like to use field injection, and you can do it with the help of `lateinit`:

```
@Component
class YourBean {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var solrClient: SolrClient
}
```

Constructor injection checks all dependencies at bean creation time and all injected fields is `val`, at other hand lateinit injected fields can be only `var`, and have little runtime overhead. And to test class with constructor, you don't need reflection.

Links:

1. [Documentation on lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties)
2. [Documentation on constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)
3. [Developing Spring Boot applications with Kotlin](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin)

Comment: can I use the `@Autowired` with primary constructor parameter?

Comment: Sure, I use primary constructor for injections in second and third example.

Comment: Can you also add the `autowired` by setter?

Comment: @IRus, you have used private vals in your example, but I would say that 80% of all examples I found on teh Internet come without "private" modifier when it comes to Kotlin. That would be considered code smell in Java. What's the reason for that? Do you happen to know? I even think it deserves a separate question.

Comment: @yuranos87 Imagine that developer injects `YourBean` in `FooBean`, in case when `YourBean` dependencies will be public (default modifier in Kotlin) developer can use `YourBean` dependencies in `FooBean` (`yourBean.mongoTemplate`). But this should not be allowed, because `YourBean` dependencies isn't his public contract, it's just implementation detail (in most cases). Instead, `FooBean` should define own dependencies in own constructor.

Comment: @IRus I couldn't agree more. That's why I asked why so many examples do not encapsulate the beans. Why leak the internal details? As you said, it can lead to "chained" calls from one bean into the other. This should be avoided at all cost because it will inevitably lead to scope creep inside the application.

Comment: The official Spring documentation says constructor injection is the recommended approach.  Thus you should list the constructor method first and also mention it's not merely your preferred approach, but the official preferred approach.
 https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin

Comment: neither the 1st nor the 2nd work for me...

Answer (score 9):

Yes, java annotations are supported in Kotlin mostly as in Java.
One gotcha is annotations on the primary constructor requires the explicit 'constructor' keyword:

From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html

> If you need to annotate the primary constructor of a class, you need to add the constructor keyword to the constructor declaration, and add the annotations before it:

```
class Foo @Inject constructor(dependency: MyDependency) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want property injection but don't like `lateinit var`, here is my solution using [property delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html):

```kotlin
private lateinit var ctx: ApplicationContext

@Component
private class CtxVarConfigurer : ApplicationContextAware {
    override fun setApplicationContext(context: ApplicationContext) {
        ctx = context
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> autowired(name: String? = null) = Autowired(T::class.java, name)

class Autowired<T : Any>(private val javaType: Class<T>, private val name: String?) {

    private val value by lazy {
        if (name == null) {
            ctx.getBean(javaType)
        } else {
            ctx.getBean(name, javaType)
        }
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value

}
```

Then you can use the much better `by` delegate syntax:

```kotlin
@Service
class MyService {

    private val serviceToBeInjected: ServiceA by autowired()

    private val ambiguousBean: AmbiguousService by autowired("qualifier")

}
```

Answer (score 6):

like that

```kotlin
@Component class Girl( @Autowired var outfit: Outfit)
```

Comment: Autowired is not needed

Comment: where is the constructor keyword here?

Comment: @vigamage Kotlin does not require `constructor` keyword for primary constructors.

Comment: not work for me... sad

Answer (score 5):

You can also autowire dependencies through the constructor. Remember to annotate your dependencies with `@Configuration, @Component, @Service` etc

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class Foo (private val dependency: MyDependency) {
    //...
}
```