# How to make @Autowired work in a regular class?

Tags: dependency-injection, spring-boot, kotlin

Here's what I've got:

```
@Component
class FooController {

    fun createFoo() {
        val foo = FooEntity()
        foo.name = "Diogo"

        fooRepository.save(foo)
    }

    @Autowired
    internal lateinit var fooRepository: FooRepository

}
```

When trying to call `createFoo()`, I get the following error:

`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property fooRepository has not been initialized`

I thought that adding a `@Component` at the top would make my class discoverable by Spring and hence make `@Autowired` work, but maybe I got it wrong?

Comment: Also take a look at different ways to inject beans in Kotlin with Spring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479631/how-to-use-spring-annotations-like-autowired-in-kotlin/35480801#35480801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm very new to Spring and was trying to call `FooController` by creating a instance of it through `new` instead of `@Autowire`ing everywhere. When I added `FooController` as a dependency of the class it was being called from, it worked.

Comment: This is what I needed, after going through dozens of tutorials and discussions.
It seems like everybody assumes this is somewhat obvious.

Answer (score 8):

Just adding `@Component` to the class is not enough.

1) When you use `@Component` you have to make sure that the class is scanned by a component scan. It depends on how you bootstrap your applciation, but you can use `<context:component-scan base-package="com.myCompany.myProject" />` for XML config or `@ComponentScan` for java configuration.

If you're using Spring boot - you don't need to declare  `@ComponentScan` yourself, because `@SpringBootApplication` inherits it and by default it scans all the classes in the current package and all it's sub packages.

2) You have to get the bean from the spring context. Creating an object with `new` will not work.

Basically there are two ways to get a bean from the application context:

- If you have an access to the ApplicationContext object then you can do something like this:

`ApplicationContext ctx = ...;
 MyBean mb = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class);//getting by type`

- Any spring bean that's declared in the context can access the other beans using dependency injection (`@Autowired`)

Comment: For the sake of clarity, if the OP is using xml-free configuration (e.g. as in Spring Boot), then that component scan can be declared in annotations as well and there won't be any need to use application context directly to get any beans. That'd be automatically done by Spring.

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot, so I don't have to declare `@ComponentScan`? Do I have to do both steps?

Comment: @dccarmo If you have `@SpringBootApplication` - it already inherits `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. I found my issue and created my own answer here. Thank you for the detailed explanation!