# Use Spring Service in simple class

Tags: java, spring

I'm working in a spring application and I'm trying to use a service class which works perfectly but not inside a simple class.
I suppose that this has to be with bean injection?? or maybe to access spring application context??

What's the best approach to solve this?

Here's my class:

```
public class RequestDatosFactura
{
JSONObject request;

private Factura factura;

@Autowired
private BitacoraService bitacoraServ;

public RequestDatosFactura(String req) throws JSONException {

    this.request = new JSONObject( req );

    this.factura = crearFactura();

}
//methods inside class...
```

This simple class tries to autowired BitacoraService, but when I instantiate, say for example into a spring controller it does well but the BitacoraService is not working.

Any guide or help will be very appreciated

Comment: Can you post specifics about what isn't working with `BitacoraService`? Also, posting your Spring configuration would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273902/how-to-make-autowired-work-in-a-regular-class

Comment: Along with specifics of working with service, you should also show how are you using the `RequestDatosFactura`. Spring will not autowire anything if you simply create it via `new` keyword.

Comment: Ok the thing with BitacoraService inside RequestDatosFactura does nothing, not even shows an error it's like knows that exists but just avoid. Ok, suppose that I don't have to instantiate by new... how do I pass the parameters so it can create the object??

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to get the service injected in the controller then pass that instance to your regular class, something like:

```
@Controller
class YourController {
    @Autowired
    private BitacoraService bitacoraService;

    public void someMethod() {
        RequestDatosFactura requestDatosFactura = new RequestDatosFactura(bitacoraService);
        // use "requestDatosFactura"
    }
}

class RequestDatosFactura {
    // ...
    private final BitacoraService bitacoraService;

    public RequestDatosFactura(final BitacoraService bitacoraService) {
        this.bitacoraService = bitacoraService;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Here: `this.requestDatosFactura = requestDatosFactura;`

Comment: It gets an error...when instantiating new RequestDatosFactura(bitacoraService), it expects a RequestDatosFactura parameter, I don't understand...