# kotlin object declaration inject class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

i am using kotlin + springboot to build my web application.
i want to create a tool class ,so i coded like above:

```
@Service
object XXXUtil{

    @Autowired
    lateinit var restTemplate: RestTemplate
    @Autowired
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    ...
}
```

but after i started the application, resTemplate cannot be injected.

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property 
restTemplate has not been initialized
```

is it because that object declaration does not allow injection or i code in a wrong way ,please help

Comment: Yes, change object to class. See accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479631/how-to-use-spring-annotations-like-autowired-in-kotlin for correct usage.

Comment: First thanks. I have tried to use class instead of object before, it does work. but i still wonder whether there is a way to use object with autowire to acheive this, not class

Comment: you can try to look at the java generated code. that will show you what's really going on.