# Is Spring autowired in Kotlin object redundant?

Tags: spring, kotlin

In the Spring framework, by default, bean scope is Singleton. But with Kotlin, we can easily create a Singleton object. Just need to do

```
object SimpleService {
  fun businessFunction() = ...
}
```

If we try to use Spring to manage the scope of a Kotlin `object`, would it be some kind of redundancy? Because I should only need to do...

- Rather than create a class and have Spring manage objects, I just need to create a Kotlin `object` (singleton).
- If we don't want to violate the *interface segregation principle*, we will create an interface and a `Service` just needs to implement it. And only need to register to Spring something like: `@Bean IMyService = SimpleSerice`

The only one thing Spring can help us with Kotlin is Spring Data (Create Repository Interface without implementation). But I think we only need to integrate with some open source for it (or create new one)

I'm concerned that Spring might be totally redundant and heavy for Kotlin.

Comment: Spring is absolutely not "totally redundant and heavy" for Kotlin, and Spring is much more than just a way to create singletons. Kotlin objects don't offer you dependency injection, for example.

Comment: Example with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845235/kotlin-object-declaration-inject-class, I saw that create Object is really easy to understand for this case. It is singleton why don't we just say it a singleton (object), rather create it as class and then request Spring trick it as Singleton

Answer (score 2):

Spring Beans have a different purpose than Kotlin objects and are not comparable per se.

With Spring beans, you get (environment-specific) configuration, dependency injection, ... . You can actually create multiple beans of the same type with different values.

When it comes to testing, you can use slices or tailor tests yourself to only instantiate the beans you absolutely need for the test. Furthermore, you can mock them.

TBOMK, kotlin object expressions are initialized when the containing file is loaded - which might not be too transparent in larger projects. This has the side effect that you might not be able to control it in tests. Also, configuration and injections have to be achieved differently. Never tried mocking ... .

I use Kotlin with Spring and have various Spring beans in action. I use companion objects and object expressions whenever I have a very static context with fast initialisation. So these objects serve more static concerns while spring beans serve dynamic ones.