# Trying to understand kotlin DI in Spring boot, at all

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

for some reason im still having huge problems grasping kotlin style DI in spring boot. Especially in JUnit tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = [(ApplicationConfig::class)])
class DataServiceTest {

private var dataService: DataService
private var addressRepository: AddressRepository

@Test
fun shouldUpdateCustomerEmail() {

    dataService.setNewCustomerEmail("1212", ApiEmail("test@test.org"))

  }
}
```

Is very simple test i have.
I've tried several style of injections.

```
private var dataService: DataService
```

Error: property must be initialized (makes sense)

```
private lateinit var dataService: DataService
```

Error: lateinit property dataService has not been initialized (well, yeah, i havent initialized it)

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var dataService: DataService
```

Error: No beans of type 'DataService' found (Why? it's fine in other services)

```
class DataServiceTest @Autowired constructor(
        private val dataService: DataService
) { ... }
```

Error: No beans of type 'DataService' found (Why? it's fine in other services)

```
private var dataService: DataService = DataService()
```

Gives no error.

but cant use same style to inject interface repository for addresses since there is **no constructor for interface**,
so repository will be uninitialized and throw error again inside `setNewCustomerEmail()`

DataService is `@Service` class with single method (for now) and works fine when called from rest but crash when called from `@Test`

```
@Service
class DataService { 

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var addressRepository: AddressRepository

    fun setNewCustomerEmail(id: String, email: ApiEmail) {
        val addressList = addressRepository.findAddressById( id.toInt() )
        ...
    }
 }
```

I do get why most of these error arise, but there seems to be many maaany ways to DI other depedencies (classes and variables) in kotlin + spring boot, but it seems to be different for every use case to next, which is fine, but i cant seem to grasp when to use what.

How do i grasp kotlin DI?

How do i inject this repository interface properly?

I've read so far:

[How to use spring annotations like @Autowired in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479631/how-to-use-spring-annotations-like-autowired-in-kotlin)

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/kotlin-when-to-use-lazy-or-lateinit/

**EDIT**
Furthermore

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/

Shows following code:

```
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long> {
  fun findByLogin(login: String): User
}
```

and then:

```
@DataJpaTest
class RepositoriesTests @Autowired constructor(
    val entityManager: TestEntityManager,
    val userRepository: UserRepository,
    val articleRepository: ArticleRepository) { ... }
```

Which is pretty much exactly what im trying here.. but if i try to do @Autowire constructor with DataService i get Error: No beans of type 'DataService' found again.

```
class DataServiceTest @Autowired constructor(
        val dataService: DataService
) ... no beans of type 'DataService' found
```

And if i try to use AddressRepository as constructor param in DataService i now ofc have to pass a Repository in, or use `@Bean`, neither one which i have?

```
class DataService @Autowired constructor(
        private val AddressRepository: AddressRepository
)
```

Im sooo super confused with this....

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using constructor injection to define all dependencies for your service:

```
@Service
class DataService(private val addressRepository: AddressRepository) {
   fun setNewCustomerEmail() {...}
}
```

Note that you can omit the @Autowired here.

To test that you could either use a plain unit test and setup the object on your own:

```
class DataServiceTest {
   val mock    = mock<AddressRepository>() // e.g. Mockito
   val service = DataService(mock)

   @Test
   fun myTest() {
     ...
   }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the SpringRunner to write an integration test. Spring will then handle creation and injection of your service and repository.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class DataServiceTest {
   @Autowired
   lateinit var dataService: DataService
}
```

As you seem to use JUnit4 AFAIK it is not possible to use constructor injection. Therefor you need to use the @Autowired/lateinit combo. When using JUnit5 it should be possible to put define an extra constructor in your test class.